# Octopus Deploy running a powershell script to create Azure Resources stopped working out of nowhere

Tags: azure, powershell, octopus-deploy

I think this is an Azure problem, but I am not confident.  Today all my deployments from Octopus stopped working. I am getting an error in the logs that makes me feel like its an authentication issue. I checked the key in Azure didnt expire. If I click the Save and Test button in Octopus its successful.  I even made a new app, assigned permissions in Azure and set it up in OCtopus and deployed using that account.  Same problem.

If I login to Powershell using the Service Principle, I can run commands everything is good, but every job is getting this error which seems like an account issue. I am currently looking at the Azure side, but nothing yet, so I thought I would ask this community as well.

```
pushd $env:OctopusCalamariWorkingDirectory
try {
  If ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean($OctopusUseServicePrincipal)) {
    # Authenticate via Service Principal
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $OctopusAzureADPassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($OctopusAzureADClientId, $securePassword)
    # Turn off context autosave, as this will make all authentication occur in memory, and isolate each session from the context changes in other sessions
    Disable-AzureRMContextAutosave -Scope Process
    $AzureEnvironment = Get-AzureRmEnvironment -Name $OctopusAzureEnvironment
    if (!$AzureEnvironment) {
      Write-Error “No Azure environment could be matched given the name $OctopusAzureEnvironment”
      exit -2
    }
    ...
```

Update 1:
Added info, I expanded the logs to Verbose and noticed this

Performing variable substitution on ‘F:\Octopus\Work\20201030000719-612-78\AppServiceEnvironment-Octopus\ase.ps1’

Attempt 1 of 5 failed: No Azure environment could be matched given the name AzureCloud

Almost like the variable substitution stopped working? Could be a red herring, but figured I would add the information.

Update 2:
I added OctopusPrintEvaluatedVariables and OctopusPrintVariables and set them to True and can see the variables are created right. It seems to be something with the connection between Azure and Octopus that stopped working

Comment: 1) It didn't "stop working out of nowhere"  2) Indentation is Good.  Showing us the end of your conditional blocks, and your catch block, is even better.  3) Are you getting a PS exception? I'm guessing "no".  4) Have you tried `Get-AzureRmEnvironment AzureCloud` and seeing if your environment is shown?  5) Have you opened a support ticket with Octopus?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  Sorry I should have used better wording for the title.   I have asked for help from Octopus.  The code block shown above is actually the error output message.  Since the script is running as part of an Octopus run, I cant really run any commands in the middle.  These deployments have been running fine for several days.  Nothing has changed on my side that I can find, but I am not the only person that touches it.